# How to reduce space between text lines?

Tags: inkscape, fonts, white-space

[image]

I set the number in red rectangle to zero, but the space between lines is still large. Is there a way to do more?

The font is Libre Baskerville.

Comment: Depending on the editing software, you might need to highlight the text - not just the text object - then make the font changes .

Comment: Which version of Inkscape you are using? I've tested that in Inkscape 1.0 with the same font and it works as expected. Could you share the svg that contains that text?

Comment: @Navaro 0.92. It turns out that I need to click the left button (the one with two Ts) to do that. I'm still not sure what it's for

Comment: You have to change the box that has the tooltip "Change spacing between baselines"

Comment: There's a bug in Inkscape 0.92 which is very glitchy. It's fixed in Inkscape 1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can increse the numbers in that red box to decrease the space between your text line

Comment: Won't increasing the number increase the space instead?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/109436)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `line-height` property in the `style` attribute.

If you're not sure on how to do it, open the *XML Editor* and select your text in the XML tree on the left, then look at the style property and modify the existing `line-height` there.

[image: XML Editor panel]

Comment: Ooops! I didn't look at the post date on this one!  LOL!